# How To remove whitespace generated at bottom of the screen using bootstrap for css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to create a simple html page , I need to cover html to full page height but small space is left at bottom ,which looks more odd when open on mobile device kindly assist
[Link For Checking](https://lp-codes.github.io/Random-Quote-Generator/)
I tried making HTML, body height to 100 % but it didn't help

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZCvz.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ,user-scalable=no" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <style>
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-bottom:0;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Random Quotes</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="container-fluid  bg-dark fa-border flex-fill">
    <h2 class="myh2 ">
      <i style="color: rgb(245, 231, 35)" class="fab fa-accusoft"></i> Random <em
        style="color: rgb(166, 250, 69)">"Quotes"</em> Generator
      <i style="color: rgb(245, 231, 35)" class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </h2>

    <div class=" container-fluid"> <img id="img" src="https://picsum.photos/1280/300/?random"
        class="rounded-circle mx-auto img-fluid m-3" />
      <div class="m-3 "
        style="background-color: rgb(235, 213, 235); border: solid; border-radius: 40px ;text-align: center;">
        <h4 style="font-size: x-large  " id="h4" class="m-1"></h4>
        <p class="bg-dark text-warning" style="font-weight: bolder ;font-size: 20px;" id="p">
        </p>
        <button style="
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          font-weight: bolder;
          color: rgb(255, 211, 211);
          background-color: #56808f;
          font-size: 20px;
          border: 3px solid;
          border-radius: 40px;
          

          
        " id="btn">
          <b>Click To Generate a Quote </b>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What is `.flex-*-grow-1`?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.min-vh-100` class from the [sizing utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport) on your first child div. See below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ,user-scalable=no" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <style>
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-bottom:0;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Random Quotes</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="container-fluid  bg-dark fa-border flex-fill min-vh-100">
    <h2 class="myh2 ">
      <i style="color: rgb(245, 231, 35)" class="fab fa-accusoft"></i> Random <em
        style="color: rgb(166, 250, 69)">"Quotes"</em> Generator
      <i style="color: rgb(245, 231, 35)" class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </h2>

    <div class=" container-fluid"> <img id="img" src="https://picsum.photos/1280/300/?random"
        class="rounded-circle mx-auto img-fluid m-3" />
      <div class="m-3 "
        style="background-color: rgb(235, 213, 235); border: solid; border-radius: 40px ;text-align: center;">
        <h4 style="font-size: x-large  " id="h4" class="m-1"></h4>
        <p class="bg-dark text-warning" style="font-weight: bolder ;font-size: 20px;" id="p">
        </p>
        <button style="
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          font-weight: bolder;
          color: rgb(255, 211, 211);
          background-color: #56808f;
          font-size: 20px;
          border: 3px solid;
          border-radius: 40px;
          

          
        " id="btn">
          <b>Click To Generate a Quote </b>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a height of 100vh to your body element.  By using vh ( View Height ) this will calculate a percentage based on the viewport's height.  100vh = 100% of your viewport.  Particularly useful for mobile browsers.  Here's some more info on its uses: https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the class `wholePage` to your div that contains all content on the page works if applying `height: 100vh;` to your body is not working.

```
.wholePage {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This CSS is native to Bootstrap with `vh-100` and `vh-min-100`